# texteditor plugin which allows the data to interact the data with another plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I am using tinymce editor to make my textarea beautiful like editor.But It does not allow the the data written inside the textarea to pass to another plugin.If I am using just textarea it works fine.

```
<html>

    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/fingerprint.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.plugin.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.laas.js"></script>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/r.png" />
        <link href="css/laas.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="tinymce.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            tinymce.init({
                selector: "textarea",
                theme: "modern",
                plugins: [
                    "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
                    "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
                    "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
                    "emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern imagetools"],
                toolbar1: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
                toolbar2: "print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons",
                image_advtab: true,
                templates: [{
                    title: 'Test template 1',
                    content: 'Test 1'
                }, {
                    title: 'Test template 2',
                    content: 'Test 2'
                }]
            });
        </script>
        <form method="post" action="somepage">
            <textarea name="content" style="width:100%"></textarea>
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/connect.js"></script>
        <section>
            <select id="idLang" name="account" class="hei">
                <option>hindi</option>
                <option>bengali</option>
            </select>
        </section>
        <br/></br>
        <textarea name="textarea" placeholder="Type Here" cols="200" rows="20" id="editorTextarea" class="reveditor"></textarea>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <script src="js/jquery.textcomplete.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

How to make the data interact with another plugin along with using tinymce editor plugin

Comment: can you elaborate what you are trying to do? "interact with another plugin" is very vague. What have you tried so far?

Comment: What ever I am typing inside the textarea that data is used by another plugin jquery.textcomplete.js.But If I use tiymce editor plugin with the id of the textarea,tinymce plugin restricts the typed data to be used by another plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Tinymce uses a contenteditable iframe and hides the former textarea.
On special events the content of the editor iframe gets written back into the textarea (or source html element).

You could use `tinymce.get('your_textarea_id').triggerSave();` to write the text back manually (test it in your javascript console).